# Google Calendar in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-calendar-api

ok i am trying to make an embedded Google calendar have some of the calenders that it is showing to be not viable until the user goes to the top corner of the calender to where there is already a drop down checkbox list with the calendars names.

the embedded Google calendar is in an `<iframe>` as you would expect and here is the code for it

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?height=600&amp;wkst=1&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;src=e63g36qa5nqqi9opb2suv7ikck%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%23875509&amp;src=u5ei2fappmnpv6a04pmuolmdl8%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%23B1440E&amp;src=ec3r1i8moit23jp7u4jnd6jjj4%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%23B1365F&amp;src=avqo4ron8pus39vp33qrt5hpg0%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%235229A3&amp;src=nci5d26158dm0f0omhpl55ieck%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%232F6309&amp;src=14a6jmfvmrjge2dh3qkabbi4og%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%232952A3&amp;ctz=Europe%2FLondon" style=" border-width:0 " width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"><script>{document.getElementById("https://www.google.com/calenda/e63g36qa5nqqi9opb2suv7ikck%40group.calendar.google.com").checked = false;}</script></iframe>
```

Comment: What is that script thing you have in the iframe element supposed to do?

Comment: it is supposed to uncheck that calendar from the check list in the top right corner so the calendar is default off